# Newtabtvplussearch removal

Tags: malware

my daughter managed to get the newtabtvplussearch malware on our machine, and i can only find solutions to remove it for windows and mac. I am running chrome, any suggestions to remove it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

As it's on chrome, there's no difference.

Open chrome and copy / paste the following into the top bar:

```
chrome://extensions
```

And then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> and search for part of the name (e.g. "New Tab").

Then click the dustbin next to it:

[image]

And it should be removed.

Comment: @Dutts As this worked, could you mark this as solved by clicking the grey check mark?